# Searching words in a dictionary C#

Tags: c#, search, dictionary

I have a text file which contains a list of about 150000 words. I loaded the the words into a dictionary and word lookup works fine for me. Now i want to search the dictionary to see if the dictionary contains a word starting from a particular alphabet.

I am using

```
foreach(KeyValuePair pair in dict ){

}
```

for this purpose. This seems to work fine for smaller word lists. But it doesnt work for 150000 wordlist. Could anyone help please.

void WordAvailable (char sLetter)
    {

```
    notAvail = true;

    int count = 0;
    do {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> pair in dict) {

            randWord = pair.Value;
            count++;

            if (randWord [0] == sLetter && !ListTest.usedWordsList.Contains (randWord)) {

                notAvail = false;
                startingLetter = char.ToString (sLetter);
                break;

            }

            if (count >= dict.Count) {

                ChooseRandomAlpha ();
                sLetter = alpha;
                count = 0;
            }

        }

    } while(notAvail);

}
```

Comment: What means "it doesnt work"? What are you doing the the loop? Also, why do you use a `Dictionary` and not a `HashSet<string>`?

Comment: Eh, `Boolean hasWord = MyDict.ContainsKey("wordToTest");`? Why on Earth loop through the dictionary?

Comment: Or if its a value hasvalue? `dict.ContainsValue("word")`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: yes, he mentioned that lookups work fine. I *guess* that he wants to find substrings.

Comment: it gives an out of bounds execiption. i tried using a dictionary with about 1000 words. It worked fine for that

Comment: as i said i want to check if the dictionary contains a word starting with a particular alphabet for example letter "s". thats why am looping through the whole dictionary.

Comment: @jibrangillani11: enumerating dictionary items shouldn't cause "index out of bounds". It is better to post your *real* code.

Comment: @Dennis Have posted the code

Comment: @jibrangillani11: the exception is raised at `randWord[0]` because there's a "word" which is an empty string. Do you store the word in the key **and** the value?

Comment: IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range. this is the error i get and this line is highlighted when i click the error. if (randWord [0] == sLetter && !ListTest.usedWordsList.Contains (randWord)) {

Comment: @jibrangillani11: yes, as i've mentioned in the comment before yours that is caused by the fact that you are trying to access the first letter from an empty string. Remove or don't add empty strings to the dictionary.

Comment: @TimSchmelter am not using any keys as the dictionary takes data from a text file containing a list of words.

Comment: @jibrangillani11: but what is the key in the dictionary? It cannot be repeating or null. That's why i've asked why you dont use a `HashSet<string>`. It seems that you don't have a value.

Comment: since the list is really large so i am not sure about the empty strings. i will check the list and get back to you guys. Thanx for all your help

Comment: thanx people. there was an empty line in the list that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I want to search the dictionary to see if the dictionary contains a word starting from a particular alphabet.

That sounds like you want a [`SortedSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070) rather than a `Dictionary`. You can use [`GetViewBetween`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381801(v=vs.110).aspx) to find all the entries in the set that lie between two bounds. The lower bound would probably be "the string you're starting with" and for the upper bound, you could either work out "the last possible string starting with those characters" or use an *exclusive* upper bound by manually ignoring anything that doesn't start with your prefix, and "incrementing" the last character of your prefix. So for example, to find all words beginning with "tim" you can use `GetViewBetween("tim", "tin")` and ignore `tin` if it's in the dictionary.

Note that ordering can be an "interesting" exercise when it comes to multiple cultures etc. If this is just an academic exercise and you'll only have ASCII characters, you might want to lower case each word as you add it to the set, and then use an ordinal comparison. If you *do* need a culture-sensitive ordering, you could make that case-insensitive easily... but working out the upper bound for the prefix will be trickier.

Example of using `GetViewBetween`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var words = new SortedSet<string>(StringComparer.Ordinal)
        {
            "cat", "dog", "banana", "laptop", "mug",
            "coffee", "microphone", "water", "stairs", "phone"
        };

        foreach (var word in words.GetViewBetween("d", "n"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word); 
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
dog
laptop
microphone
mug
```

An alternative would be to build your own [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) implementation (or find an existing one) but I don't know of one in the BCL.

Comment: Thanks for recalling `GetViewBetween`. But i'm not sure if he needs to find all strings in a range of starting letters but only to "check if the dictionary contains a word starting with a particular letter" +1

Comment: @TimSchmelter: To find all words beginning with "tim" you can use `GetViewBetween("tim", "tin")`

Comment: would a sorted set be as fast as a dictionary and would it abe able to handle a large list of words?

Comment: @Jon: Yes, nice to know. But i think the requirement is much simpler according to his description. He wants to know if the dictionary contains at least one word which starts with a given letter (or multiples). So `dict.Keys.Any(s => s.StartsWith("a"))`

Comment: @TimSchmelter: And that's an O(N) lookup, whereas mine isn't :) Judging by the question, I think efficiency is important.

Comment: @jibrangillani11: It won't be as fast for looking up a single word exactly - but it will be *much* faster for looking up words in a range, which is effectively what you're trying to do. Dictionaries are good for *equality* matching, but that's not what you're looking for. I'm assuming that "from a particular alphabet" you mean "starting with a particular sequence of letters" by the way - it's not very clear from your question.

Comment: IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range. this is the error i get and this line is highlighted when i click the error. if (randWord [0] == sLetter && !ListTest.usedWordsList.Contains (randWord)) {

Comment: @jibrangillani11: Well that will happen if `randWord` is an empty string... but you should give that information *in the question*.

Comment: since the list is really large so i am not sure about the empty strings. i will check the list and get back to you guys. Thanx for all your help

Comment: thanx people. there was an empty line in the list that was causing the issue.